# Getting value from object vs getting value from global value

Tags: javascript, performance, premature-optimization

I know this is premature optimization but I am just curious to know
how long does it take to get the value of this

```
var objects =
{
    number:10
}
console.log(""+objects.number);
```

VS

```
var number = 10;
console.log("" + number);
```

I just do not know how to benchmark so if I knew I would do it myself but if this is a really bad question please do not -rep me, just tell me and I'll remove the question

Comment: do you really think there will be a difference? http://jsperf.com/

Comment: Like a intense physic game in a loop that runs every second running on a older android phone, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/comparing-speed-of-getting-var-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results are intensely varying.
See this test: http://jsperf.com/property-vs-plain-variable

Run it many times, you can see the results orbit around, without a definitive result (at least on Firefox). Sometimes accessing a variable is slower than accessing the object's property directly, I think you can assume there is no real difference.

Comment: I did the test on chrome and getting the value directly instead of having a object was faster. I think I'll use this for myself since it'll require less typing for me  :D'

Comment: I just added a new test that might give us another interesting insight: if the property being accessed from the object has a getter, it will be called each time it's accessed, and caching it will cache the return of the getter, increasing speed.

Comment: Ahahaha I might have introduced some complexity to the tests, but, I'll try to explain. A property can have a getter, which is a function that is called secretly everytime someone asks for that property in that object. When we save the result of this call, we don't call it again at every frame (test sample), thus giving a speed comparable with a local variable.

Comment: Also, since most browsers deoptimize `object = {x: 1}`'s `x` to a getter that returns `1`, we get an approximately equal value for our speed, and the only thing that matters in the end is if we cache it or not. And since Javascript is single threaded (exactly one piece of code executes at any given time), caching values of properties in the scope (function) that will use it makes perfect sense and has no side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Using local values is faster than getting objects value
http://jsperf.com/comparing-speed-of-getting-var-in-javascript

Comment: Run it again. I just got object access being faster by 16%!
It would be interesting to know the reasons behind this...

Comment: I did the test from the Kroltan and getting the cached value was faster.... I though they should had been same as the direct value